# On the premises vs at the premises

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between on the premises and at the premises.

Example:

There was no evidence to show that the recycling activity was carried out on the premises/ at the premises.

Comment: "Do you do it all *here*?" "Yes - it's all done on the premises." "What do they use 22, Hill Street for?" "Recycling is carried out at the premises." If you say, "There was no evidence to show that *THE* recycling......" you need "*ON* the premises". If you say, "There was no evidence to show that recycling..... " you need "*AT the premises." In everyday use they're rather interchangeable though.

Comment: Thank you so much